# MyLinkedList current node is only not-null within the structure. When method MyLinkedList.first() returns, current is reset to null

Tags: java, linked-list, scope, null

I apologize in advance if I break any etiquette. I have never posted a question before.
I was unable to find advice for my problem elsewhere online.
I am writing an `EvolvingStrings` program in Java and I am running into issues when using `MyLinkedList.first()`. `Current` is set to the `first` node within the method call, but on return `current` is reset to null. The linked list is of a user defined type `Genome`.
When running my test class `EvolutionTest.java`, my program runs infinitely because my Strings are never evolved, and therefore never reach their target. I have traced a bug to `Population.nextGeneration()`. Specifically, line 127 in the class `Population`.
The method should set population's current node to first. It does do this, however, only inside the method call. On return, current is reset to null.
If anyone has any advice as to the problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

This is my population class.

```
/**
 * FileName: Population.java
 * CreatedOn: August 17, 2022
 *
 * @author rodew
 * @version 1.0.081722
 */

/**
 * A class that contains a list of Genomes
 * representing all the Strings in a virtual world.
 * In this world, all that exists are strings of
 * characters from the set: {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,
 * K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,' ',-,'}
 * Strings in this world can reproduce new strings
 * and die if they are not fit enough.
 */
public class Population {

    /**
     * The number of genomes in the population.
     * For this assignment, population size is 100.
     */
    protected final int SIZE;

    /**
     * The number of times nextGeneration
     * has been called.
     */
    public int generation;

    /**
     * This stores the most fit genome, which
     * is the genome with the highest fitness
     * level.
     */
    public Genome mostFit;

    /**
     * This stores the Genomes in the population.
     * The initial population of size SIZE is
     * created in the constructor. The population
     * is updated every time nextGeneration is
     * called.
     */
    public MyLinkedList<Genome> population;

    /**
     * Default Constructor.
     * Calls the main constructor with
     * String "FIRST MIDDLE LAST" and
     * integer 100.
     */
    public Population() {   this("FIRST MIDDLE LAST", 100);    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * Initializes SIZE to populationSize.
     * Initializes generation to zero.
     * Initializes population to a linkedList with
     * 100 baby (Empty) Genomes.
     * Initializes Genome.Target to a linkedList
     * consisting of the characters from the target
     * String.
     * Initializes mostFit to the first Genome in the
     * population.
     * @param target the target Genome for evolution.
     * @param populationSize the number of Genomes in the
     * population.
     */
    public Population(String target, int populationSize) {

        SIZE = populationSize;
        generation = 0;
        population = new MyLinkedList<>();
        Genome.target = createTarget(target);

        for(int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++) population.addToEnd(new Genome());

        mostFit = population.first();

    }

    /**
     * Creates a MyLinkedList from passed String.
     * @param str the String from which the list is created.
     * @return the target linkedList.
     */
    public MyLinkedList<Character> createTarget(String str) {

        MyLinkedList<Character> target = new MyLinkedList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

            char ch = str.charAt(i);

            target.addToEnd(ch);

        }

        return target;

    }

    /**
     * Updates the population with the next
     * generation. First, half the population
     * with the lowest fitness levels are deleted.
     * Second, new Genomes are created from the
     * remaining population. There is equal chance
     * that (1) a random remaining Genome will be
     * cloned and the clone mutated or (2) a random
     * remaining Genome will be cloned, the clone
     * crossed with another Genome, and then finally
     * mutated. Third, the population will be sorted
     * by fitness level. Last, the mostFit Genome will
     * be updated to the Genome with the highest fitness
     * level.
     */
    public void nextGeneration() {

        int select;
        int half = SIZE / 2;
        Genome adult;
        Genome offspring;

        population.first();

        for(int i = 0; i < half; i++) population.next();

        while (population.current() != null) population.remove();

        for(int n = 0; n < half; n++) {

            select = Genome.random() % half;
            adult = population.first();

            for (int i = 0; i < select; i++) adult = population.next();

            offspring = new Genome(adult);

            if (Genome.random() % 2 == 0) {

                select = Genome.random() % half;
                adult = population.first();

                for (int i = 0; i < select; i++) adult = population.next();

                offspring.crossover(adult);

            }

            offspring.mutate();
            population.addToEnd(offspring);

        }

        population.sort(true);
        generation++;

        mostFit = population.first();

    }

    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("[\n");
        Genome current = population.first();

        while (current != null) {

            str.append(current).append("\n");

            current = population.next();

        }

//        str = new StringBuilder(str.substring(0, str.length() - 2));


        return str.append("]").toString();

    }
}
```

This is my linked list class.

```
/**
 * FileName: MyLinkedList.java
 * CreatedOn: July 8, 2022
 * @author rodew
 * @version 4.0.081722
 */

/**
 * Processes a generic list of elements by implementing a Linked List.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MyLinkedList<Type extends Comparable<Type>> {
    /**
     * A reference to the first node in the list.
     * Is null if the list is empty.
     */
    protected Node first;

    /**
     * A reference to the last node in the list.
     * Is null if the list is empty.
     */
    protected Node last;

    /**
     * A reference to the current node in the list.
     * Initialized to null.
     * When this node is null, the current node has fallen off the end of the list.
     */
    protected Node current;

    /**
     * A reference to the previous node in the list.
     * Is null if current is equal to first.
     */
    protected Node previous;

    /**
     * The number of elements stored in the list.
     */
    protected int size;

    /**
     * The total number of comparisons made with the list.
     */
    public long comparisons;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     * Initializes first, current, and previous to null.
     * Initializes size to zero.
     * Initializes comparisons to zero.
     */
    public MyLinkedList() {

        first       = null;
        last        = null;
        current     = null;
        previous    = null;
        size        = 0;
        comparisons = 0;

    }

    /**
     * Inserts the passed item before the current node.
     * Runtime: O(1).
     * @param item the element to be inserted.
     */
    public void addBefore(Type item) {

        // Try to get two cases
        // 1: previous != null
        // else
        if (first == null) {            //  Case is only true once

            first       = new Node(item, current);
            last        = first;
            previous    = first;

        } else if (current == first) {

            first       = new Node(item, current);

        } else if (current == null) {

            last.next = new Node(item, null);
            last = last.next;
            previous = last;

        } else {

            Node temp   = previous;

            previous    = new Node(item, current);
            temp.next   = previous;

        }

        size++;

    }

    /**
     * Inserts the passed item after the current node.
     * Does nothing if the current node is null.
     * Runtime: O(1).
     * @param item the element to be inserted.
     */
    public void addAfter(Type item) {

        if (current == null) return;

        current.next    = new Node(item, current.next);

        if (current == last) last = current.next;

        size++;

    }

    /**
     * Adds the item to the front of the list.
     * Runtime: O(1)
     * @param item the element to be added to the front of the list.
     */
    public void addToFront(Type item) {

        if (first == null || current == first) {

            first = new Node(item, first);
            last = first;
            previous = first;

        } else first = new Node(item, first);

        size++;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the item to the end of the list.
     * Runtime: O(1)
     * @param item the element to be added to the end of the list.
     */
    public void addToEnd(Type item) {

        if (first == null) {

            first = new Node(item, null);
            last = first;
            previous = first;

        } else {

            last.next = new Node(item, null);
            last = last.next;

            if (current == null) previous = last;

        }

        size++;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the item stored in the current node.
     * Returns null if the current node is null.
     * Runtime: O(1).
     * @return the item in the current node.
     */
    public Type current() {

        if (current == null) { return null; }

        return current.item;

    }

    /**
     * Sets the current node to be the first node.
     * Returns null if the first node is null.
     * Runtime: O(1).
     * @return the item stored in the current node after the update.
     */
    public Type first() {

        if (first == null) { return null; }

        current = first;
        previous = null;

        return current.item;

    }

    /**
     * Sets the previous node to be the current node and then sets the current node
     * to be the next node in the list.
     * Returns null if the current node is null.
     * Runtime: O(1).
     * @return the item stored in the current node after the update.
     */
    public Type next() {

        if (current == null) { return null; }

        previous    = current;
        current     = current.next;

        if (current == null) { return null; }

        return current.item;

    }

    /**
     * Removes the current node.
     * If current is null, does nothing but return null.
     * Runtime: O(1).
     * @return the item removed.
     */
    public Type remove() {

        if (current == null) return null;

        Node temp       = current;

        if (current == first) {

            first = first.next;

        } else {

            previous.next   = current.next;

        }

        if (current == last) last = previous;

        current         = current.next;
        size--;

        return temp.item;

    }

    /**
     * Backwards compatible (Ascending) Bubble Sort.
     * Calls sort(descending) by passing
     * false value as boolean.
     * Runtime: 0(n^2)
     */
    public void sort() {    sort(false);    }

    /**
     * Bubble Sort Algorithm.
     * Allows sorting the list in
     * ascending or descending order.
     * Runtime: O(n^2)
     * @param descending if true, sort order is descending;
     * otherwise, sort order is ascending.
     */
    public void sort(boolean descending) {

        Node current = first;

        while (current != null ) {

            Node next = current.next;

            while(next != null ) {

                if (descending) {

                    if (current.item.compareTo(next.item) < 0) {

                        Type temp = current.item;

                        current.item = next.item;
                        next.item = temp;

                    }

                } else {

                    if (current.item.compareTo(next.item) > 0) {

                        Type temp = current.item;

                        current.item = next.item;
                        next.item = temp;

                    }
                }

                next = next.next;

            }

            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Moves the current node to the front of the list.
     * Runtime: O(1)
     * @return the item inside the node moved.
     */
    public Type moveToFront() {

        if (current == null) return null;

        addToFront(remove());

        current = first;

        return current.item;

    }

    /**
     * Swaps the current node with the previous node.
     * Runtime: O(1)
     * @return the item swapped closer to the front of the list.
     */
    public Type swap() {

        if (current == null) return null;
        else if (current == first) return current.item;

        Type temp = current.item;
        current.item = previous.item;
        previous.item = temp;

        return temp;

    }

    /**
     * Searches the nodes for the passed item.
     * Runtime: O(n).
     * @param item the element to be searched for.
     * @return true if item is found, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean contains(Type item) {

        Node temp       = first;

        while (temp != null) {

            comparisons++;

            if (temp.item.compareTo(item) == 0) { return true; }

            temp = temp.next;

        }

        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in the list.
     * Runtime: O(1).
     * @return the number of elements in the list.
     */
    public int size() { return size; }

    /**
     * Returns true if size is zero.
     * Runtime: O(1).
     * @return true if size is zero, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() { return size == 0; }

    /**
     * Displays the contents of the list.
     * Runtime: O(n).
     * @return the string representation of the list of items.
     */
    public String toString() {

        if (isEmpty()) { return "[]"; }         // Only true in one situation

        Node temp       = first;

        StringBuilder listString = new StringBuilder("[" + temp.toString());

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {        // while loops are usually more efficient

            temp = temp.next;

            listString.append(", ").append(temp.toString());

        }

        listString.append("]");

        return listString.toString();

    }

    protected class Node {

        /**
         * The item stored in this node.
         */
        Type item;

        /**
         * A reference to the next node in the list.
         * Is null if there is no next node.
         */
        Node next;

        /**
         * Default Constructor.
         * Instantiates item to the passed element.
         * Instantiates the next node reference to the passed node.
         * @param item the element to be stored.
         * @param next the reference to the next node in the list.
         */
        public Node(Type item, Node next) {

            this.item = item;
            this.next = next;

        }

        /**
         * Returns the toString of item.
         * @return the toString of item.
         */
        public String toString() {

            return item.toString();

        }
    }
}
```

This is my Genome class

```
/**
 * FileName: Genome.java
 * CreatedOn: August 17, 2022
 *
 * @author rodew
 * @version 1.0.081722
 */

/**
 * A class that contains a list of characters
 * representing a String in a virtual world.
 * In this world, all that exists are strings of
 * characters from the set: {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,
 * K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,' ',-,'}
 * Strings in this world can reproduce new strings
 * and die if they are not fit enough.
 */
public class Genome implements Comparable<Genome>{

    /**
     * Seed for random().
     */
    protected static Integer seed = 2067734636;

    /**
     * A list of characters representing the string
     * encoded by the genome.
     */
    protected MyLinkedList<Character> genes;

    /**
     * The population's mutation rate.
     * Accurate only to two decimal places.
     * Default: 5% chance of mutation.
     */
    protected static double mutationRate = 0.05;

    /**
     * The target string.
     */
    protected static MyLinkedList<Character> target = new MyLinkedList<>();

    /**
     * The set of characters all strings are made from.
     */
    protected static final MyLinkedList<Character> genePool = getDNA();

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Initializes genes to an empty list.
     */
    public Genome() {   genes = new MyLinkedList<>();       }

    /**
     * Copy constructor.
     * Initializes genes to the passed genome's genes.
     * @param genome the list of characters to be copied.
     */
    public Genome(Genome genome) {  genes = genome.genes;       }

    /**
     * My random number generator.
     * @return a random 32 bit integer.
     */
    protected static int random() {

        int a = 923743637;
        int b = 3;
        long c = (long) Math.pow(2, 48);

        seed = (int) ((a * seed + b) % c);

        return seed;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the genePool with characters:
     * {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,
     * U,V,W,X,Y,Z,' ',-,'}
     * @return the genePool
     */
    protected static MyLinkedList<Character> getDNA() {

        MyLinkedList<Character> characters = new MyLinkedList<>();
        int index = 65;

        while (index < 91) characters.addToEnd((char) index++);       // Characters 'A'-'Z'

        characters.addToEnd((char) 32);         //  ' ' character
        characters.addToEnd((char) 45);         //  '-' character
        characters.addToEnd((char) 39);         //  ''' character

        return characters;
    }

    /**
     * Mutation chance simulator.
     * @return true if successful; false otherwise.
     */
    protected static boolean mutationSuccess() {

        double threshold = mutationRate * 100;

        return (random() % 100) <= threshold;

    }

    /**
     * Mutates the genes.
     * With mutationRate chance, add a randomly selected
     * character to a randomly selected position in genes.
     * With mutationRate chance, delete a single character
     * from a randomly selected position in genes; only
     * if genes.size() >= 1.
     * Each character in genes, with mutationRate chance
     * is replaced by a random character.
     */
    public void mutate() {

        int select;
        char gene;

        if (mutationSuccess() & genes.first() != null) {

            select = random() % 29;
            gene = genePool.first();

            genes.first();

            for (int i = 0; i < select; i++) gene = genePool.next();

            select = random() % genes.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < select; i++) genes.next();

            genes.remove();
            genes.addBefore(gene);

        }

        if (mutationSuccess() & genes.first() != null) {

            select = random() % genes.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < select; i++) genes.next();

            genes.remove();

        }

        genes.first();

        while (genes.current() != null) {

            if(mutationSuccess()) {

                genes.remove();

                select = random() % 29;
                gene = genePool.first();

                for (int i = 0; i < select; i++) gene = genePool.next();

                genes.addBefore(gene);

            } else genes.next();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This updates genes by crossing it with the passed genome.
     * The new genes list is created by randomly selecting one
     * of the parent genomes and adding that character to the
     * new genes list; if the position does not exist in the
     * parent, the new list will end at that position.
     * @param parent the genome to be crossed with.
     */
    public void crossover(Genome parent) {

        MyLinkedList<Character> child = new MyLinkedList<>();
        Character mother = genes.first();
        Character father = parent.genes.first();

        while (mother != null) {

            if (random() % 2 == 0) child.addToEnd(mother);

            else if (father != null) child.addToEnd(father);

            else break;

            mother = genes.next();
            father = parent.genes.next();

        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns the fitness level of the genome using
     * the following formula: -(l + d), where l is the
     * difference in length between the target and the
     * genes and d is the number of characters that
     * are incorrect.
     * @return the fitness level.
     */
    public int fitness() {

        int d = 25;
        int l = target.size() - genes.size();

        Character self = genes.first();
        Character other = target.first();

        while (self != null & other != null) {

            if (self.compareTo(other) == 0) d--;

            self = genes.next();
            other = target.next();

        }

        while (self != null) {

            d++;
            self = genes.next();

        }

       return -(l + d);
    }

    /**
     * Compares the fitness level of the genome with
     * the fitness level of the other genome.
     * @param other the genome to be compared with.
     * @return a negative integer, zero, or a positive
     * integer as this genome's fitness level is less
     * than, equal to, or greater than the specified
     * genome's fitness level.
     */
    public int compareTo(Genome other) {    return this.fitness() - other.fitness();        }

    /**
     * Displays the genome and its fitness level
     * in this format: ("genes", fitness)
     * @return the string format of the genome.
     */
    public String toString() {

        if (genes.isEmpty()) return "(\"\", -50)";

        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("(");
        String genome = genes.toString();

        genome = genome.replace('[', '"');
        genome = genome.replace(']', '"');
        genome = genome.replaceAll(",", "");

        string.append(genome).append(", ").append(this.fitness()).append(')');

        return string.toString();

    }
}
```

This is the test class.

```
/**
 * FileName: EvolutionTest.java
 * CreatedOn: August 18, 2022
 *
 * @author rodew
 * @version 1.0.081822
 */

import org.junit.Test;
/**
 * JUnit test for my Population and Genome Classes
 */
public class EvolutionTest {

    @Test
    public final void construct() {

        System.out.println("Strings are now evolving...");

        long delta, startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Population pop = new Population("FIRST MIDDLE LAST", 100);

        while(pop.mostFit.fitness() < 0) {

            System.out.print("... Generation " + pop.generation + " ");
            System.out.println(pop.mostFit);

            pop.nextGeneration();

        }

        delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        System.out.println("Evolution took " + delta + " milliseconds.");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

My code is on gitHub: https://github.com/rodew374/EvolvingStrings.

Comment: Is `current` null or is `current.item` null? They are different things, and it might be an issue with the inner `item` variable not being set correctly somewhere. If you want more help please include the full error in your question, and include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: `current` is null.
I do not need the `current.item`, so I do not assign it to a variable.
I am only using `MyLinkedList.first()` to iterate through the list to a certain node.

Comment: The value of `current` is set to the non null value of `first`, it will not be null unless there is relevant code that you have not shown us. Please edit your question to show the error and the code as noted above.

Comment: The error is that `current` is only equal to the first item in the list inside the method call. As soon as `first()` returns to `Population`, `current` is null.
That is what I don't understand. There is no way that I know of that `current` can be equal to anything but what it was set to inside `first()` unless some other method changes it.
I will include the surrounding code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add some debugging to your `nextGeneration()` method to see if current is null or not. We can do this with the following:

```
System.out.println("Before: "+population.current.toString());
population.first();
System.out.println("After: "+population.current.toString());
```

And the results are:

```
Before: ("", -50)
After: ("", -50)
```

As we can see, `current` is not null, it is returning results both before and after calling `population.first();`. Instead your issue is that the values of `current` and `first` are never updated.

You have far too much code for any of us to sort through, so you will need to do some of your own debugging to work out why the values are not being updated.

Hint 1: Inside your `mutate()` method the statement `if (mutationSuccess() & genes.first() != null) {` is NEVER true, so the following line in NEVER called `genes.addBefore(gene);` which may be one of the causes why `current` and `first` never change.

Hint 2: Find all locations in your code where a new Node is created and assigned to `first` or `current`, and check the values that are being inserted.